# Kendo Mobile - Incorrect device detection when using iPod

Tags: kendo-mobile

When testing my application with an iPod, the value found in `kendo.support.mobileOS.device`
reads as "iphone"

Obviously, this is wrong, and I did another test using `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(iphone|ipod)/)` and the value reads correctly as "ipod,ipod"

Is this a bug in Kendo? Or am I looking in the wrong place for my device name?

I am using Kendo UI Complete v2013.1.319 and an iPod (Model MC540LL/A) with iOS v6.1.3

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, but rather a decision - functionally the browser in iPhone and iPod is the same, hence we report iphone only.

Comment: Fair enough, but the documentation suggests iPod and iPhone are both handled respectively, given the documentation link here: [link](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#force-ios-5-look)


More specifically, this line:
'device: "ipad" // Mobile device, can be "ipad", "iphone", "ipod", "android" "fire", "blackberry", "meego", "wp"'

In my opinion, this is a bit misleading, as ipod is not reported. Anyhow, thanks for clarifying.